# JavaScript and iframe style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm working with HTML, CSS and JS to make a web application.

I have an html page with an iframe into it (they are in the same domain) and I'd like to change the iframe's style when I click on a button.

So, in the main page I have a button

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="refreshFrame()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Refresh
</button>
```

which, when clicked, calls

```
function refreshFrame() {
    $("iframe").contents().find(".page-content").css("color", "blue");
}
```

The problem is that this code seems to work. The text in the page-content div change its color but it seems that the iframe instantaneously refreshes and the color returns black.

Can you help me?

Comment: Is this button placed within a `form` element? If so, add `type="button"` to `button`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is a submit button. If the page refreshes, then it is most likely because the button is inside a form.

You are running the JS, then submitting the form, which reloads the page.

Add `type="button"` for a JS-only button.